# not able to call model function in controller in magento

Tags: magento, model, controller, call

I am new in magento. I am trying to call model's method in my controller's action, but not able to do that. My folder structure is :

[image]

My controller is :

```
class Pw_Manageproducts_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    public function indexAction() {
      $model = Mage::getModel('manageproducts/manageproducts');
       //trying to call modelCalls() which is in model class
       //$model->modelCalls();
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

config.xml file for model setting :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <manageproducts>
                <class>Manageproducts_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>Manageproducts_Mysql4</resourceModel>
                <manageproducts_mysql4>
                    <class>Pw_Manageproducts_Model_Mysql4</class>
                    <entities>
                        <manageproducts>
                            <table>blog_posts</table>
                        </manageproducts>
                    </entities>               
                </manageproducts_mysql4>
            </manageproducts>
         </models>   
    </global>
</config>
```

block is like:

```
class Pw_Manageproducts_Block_Manageproducts extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function showAll(){
        echo "Srimanta";
    }
}
```

Model is like:

```
class Pw_Manageproducts_Model_Manageproducts extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {
    public function _construct() {
        $this->_init('manageproducts/manageproducts');
    }
    public function modelCalls(){
        return "This is a model function";
    }
}
```

I want to call `modelCalls()` function in `IndexController`. But it is not happening.
Also my ultimate goal is to show messages(which are in modelCalls() methiod in model and showAll() method in block) in view page which is in `design/frontend/default/default/template/pw/manageproducts/manageproducts.phtml`
Please let me know where did I make the mistake also let me know please whether my procedure is correct or not.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to specify your block class in your config.xml to call block function from template file

Comment: I mention that too by <blocks>
            <manageproducts>
                <class>Pw_Manageproducts_Block</class>
            </manageproducts>
        </blocks>

Comment: Try this once
`public function modelCalls(){$text = "This is a model function"; 
        return $text;}`

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy No, it is nshowing Call to a member function modelCalls() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\letsgobanana\app\code\local\Pw\Manageproducts\controllers\IndexController.php on line 12

Answer (score 1):

You issue is in resource model definition

```
<resourceModel>Manageproducts_Mysql4</resourceModel>
```

Should be

```
<resourceModel>manageproducts_mysql4<resourceModel>
```

Code of  `Pw>Manageproducts>Model>Mysql4>Manageproducts.php`
should be

```
 <?php

    class Pw_Manageproducts_Model_Mysql4_Manageproducts extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
    {
        public function _construct()
        {   
            $this->_init('manageproducts/manageproducts', 'manageproducts_id');
        }
    }
```

More details [check](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table)

Comment: Any other suggestion please?

Comment: How are you calling `modelCalls` in your `IndexController` ?

Comment: I am trying to call by $model = Mage::getModel('manageproducts/manageproducts');
       //trying to call modelCalls() which is in model class
       $model->modelCalls();

Is it not possible?\

Comment: You can simply call it like `$model = Mage::getModel('manageproducts/manageproducts')` to fetch your collection

Answer (score 0):

I have done the changes in my module checked it with your requirement & its working so please find below code.

Below is my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Test_Helloworld>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
            <!-- Version of module -->
        </Test_Helloworld>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <helloworld>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Test_Helloworld</module>
                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                    <!-- This is the URL
 of the module. i.e www.yourmagento.com/index.php/helloworld will be the url of your module. -->
                </args>
            </helloworld>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <helloworld>
                    <file>helloworld.xml</file>
                </helloworld>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <helloworld>
                <class>Test_Helloworld_Block</class>
                <!-- Path of the
 Block Folder, where all php files are located related to view -->
            </helloworld>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <helloworld>
                <class>Test_Helloworld_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>helloworld_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </helloworld>
            <helloworld_mysql4>
                <class>Test_Helloworld_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <helloworld>
                        <table>friendlist</table>
                        <!-- Actual table name in sql  -->
                    </helloworld>
                </entities>
            </helloworld_mysql4>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <helloworld>
                <class>Test_Helloworld_Helper</class>
                <!-- Path of Helper Files -->
            </helloworld>
        </helpers>
        <resources>
            <!-- These are resource setting giving access to module, read/write permission on database -->
            <helloworld_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Test_Helloworld</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </helloworld_setup>
            <helloworld_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </helloworld_write>
            <helloworld_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </helloworld_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <!--This is acl based on URL. If you see URL it would be /admin/system_config/ -->
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <test translate="title" module="helloworld">
                                            <!-- This is name of the section created by us -->
                                            <title>Test Section ACL</title>
                                            <!-- Title as shown in User->Roles->Permissions Window -->
                                            <sort_order>99</sort_order>
                                        </test>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Below is my model file where i have declared my test function.

```
class Test_Helloworld_Model_Helloworld extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('helloworld/helloworld'); // this is location of the resource file.
    }
    public function testMassge()
    {
       return "hi";
    }
}
```

call above function in controller:

```
<?php echo Mage::getModel('helloworld/helloworld')->testMassge(); ?>
```

So please compare it with your module structure.hopefully it will help you.